# mysql connection in php function not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session-cookies

I'm trying to build a login system on a website. First, I wrote a file called "userConn.php" which is used to connect with MySQL. The code is shown below:

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '******************');
define('DB_NAME', 'userinfo');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Then I wrote a file called "login.php". This file calls the "userConn.php" file to connect to the database and subsequently, compares the Username and Password entered with the records in the database. If a match is found, a session is started and the user is redirected to the homepage. Before redirecting, a function called "onLogin" is called to issue a token for the username to be used as a rememberme cookie. This function calls another function named "storeTokenForUser" to store the token and the username in a database table. The problem is that the sql statement in the latter function is not storing any data in the database table after a login is made.

The code of "login.php" can be found hereunder:

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'userConn.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
        $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            /* Password is correct, so start a new session and
                        save the username to the session */
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
                            onLogin($username);
                            header("location: new_homepage.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = 'No account found with that username.';
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}

function onLogin($user) {
    $token = random_bytes(256); // generate a token, should be 128 - 256 bit
    $SECRET_KEY = random_bytes(256);
    storeTokenForUser($user, $token);
    $cookie = $user . ':' . $token;
    $mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $cookie, $SECRET_KEY);
    $cookie .= ':' . $mac;
    setcookie('rememberme', $cookie);
}

function storeTokenForUser($usernameTok, $tokenvalue){
    global $link;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tokens (username, tokenvalue) VALUES ('".$usernameTok."', '".$tokenvalue."')";
    $link->query($sql);
}
?>
```

Can someone give me an explanation of why the SQL in the "storeTokenForUser" function is not working and a solution to repair this?

I tried the code below as well for the "storeTokenForUser" function but it did not work:

```
function storeTokenForUser($usernameTok, $tokenvalue){
    global $link;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tokens (username, tokenvalue) VALUES (?, ?)";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_token);

            $param_username = $usernameTok;
            $param_token = $tokenvalue;

            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Check for errors: `$link->query($sql) or die($link->error);`

Comment: Why do you switch between the procedural and OO mysqli interfaces? Stick with OO, it's easier to read and write.

Comment: Use a prepared statement in `storeTokenForUser` instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. Add additional code to the end of your question (don't remove the original code).

Comment: I believe the problem now is the data type for the column to store $tokenvalue as I checked the error msg. Is a BLOB ideal to store such variable?

Comment: Usually CHAR is the appropriate type for a string of a few dozen characters.